# How can I convert an entire input file into a string?

Tags: java

In Java, how would I convert an **entire** input file into one `String`?

In other words, if I have an input file `"test.in"`:

```
c++
java
python
test
```

then I want to create a `String` containing `"c++javapythontest"`.

I thought of something along the lines of

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("test.in"));
while(input.hasNext()){
    String test = test + input.nextLine();
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work.
Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Think about the first iteration of that loop. `test` is undefined, so what is there to add to?

Comment: So you want to discard all newlines?

Comment: `FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("test.in");                             byte[] byteArray=new byte[fis.availble()]; fis.read(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);                                                 String str=new String(byteArray);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To read file contents, discarding newline chars:

```
String contents = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.in")).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

---

I think you needed to test for `hasNextLine()`, and your code's performance suffers from the creation of so many objects when you concatenate strings like that. If you changed your code to use a `StringBuilder`, it would run much faster.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many ways to do it. One of the ways you can try is using the `nio` package classes. You can use the `readAllBytes` method of the `java.nio.file.Files` class to get a `byte array` first and then create a new String object from the byte array `new String(bytes)`.

Read the [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) of this method.

Following is a sample program:

```
byte[] bytes= Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
String fileContent = new String(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the String test out of the loop, then iterate filling it.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a small modification to your original logic. 
[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) creates a mutable sequence of characters which means we just append the content to the value of StringBuilder object instead of creating a new object everytime.

In your code `String test = test + input.nextLine();` was inside `while` loop. 
 
Thus fresh objects of String test were created with every iteration of while loop and therefore it was not saving previous values.

```
String path = "test.txt";
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(path));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (input.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(input.nextLine() + "\n");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead.
Its a simple one liner

`String str = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/file")));`

This reads the entire file and keeps it as String.
If you want to remove new line characters.

`str.replace("\n", "");`

Answer (score 0):

`String.join` has been added in `Java8` which internally uses `StringBuilder`

```
String content = String.join("", Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("test.in")));
```